# "listening to me about as much as you're listening to this pole here"

Tags: the-matrix

There's one scene in Enter The Matrix I don't understand.

Ghost and Niobe has just returned from a mission in the Matrix but Niobe tells Sparks (their operator) that they must go again. She explains that Morpheus called and said that he needs help.

> Sparks: He says he needs your help. Can you imagine what that means?
>   Our help? He's got Neo, why does he need you? I know you're both
>   listening to me about as much as you're listening to **this pole here**,
>   so I'll just tell you what I think: I think you just spent eight of
>   your nine lives getting out of there...

Could you tell me what he means by "this pole here"?

Full dialogue: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0277828/characters/nm0938931

You can watch the scene for yourself:

Comment: @ToddWilcox Questions like this are [on-topic here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11627/31394). And I strongly suspect this one would be closed on [elu.se] for "lack of research" (ELU is *very* strict on closing questions). So no, definitely shouldn't be moved.

Comment: @Randal'Thor [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), then?

Comment: @ToddWilcox the thing is, I've already asked this question in a forum for learners but couldn't get an answer that would satisfy me. I wanted to get an answer from someone who knows the universe. I just thought that perhaps by the pole Sparks meant the connecting plug they use to enter the matrix (to  "jack in"). Sorry if my question sounds stupid to you.

Comment: This is definitely not a stupid question at all. I just wondered if it might be more about how the English language is used and less about science fiction specifically. Rand al'Thor has clarified that there's nothing wrong with asking this question here. I'm sorry the other forum wasn't helpful and I hope the answer from Valorum has helped.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

He simply means that he thinks that they're going to ignore his opinion entirely. That they won't even hear what he says and that they've already made up their minds.

He could just as easily have said,

> *"I know you're both listening to me about as much as you're listening to this **wall panel** here*

or

> *"I know you're both listening to me about as much as you're listening to this **cup holder** here*

etc.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, Valorum. However, there's just one little thing I don't understand. There's no actual pole anywhere around. In other words, Sparks essentially could mention any object? Even your "this cup holder here" would do?

Comment: @Fateman When I watch it, it seems like there **is** a pole that is just not visible in the shot. When he says "this pole here", he looks to the side for just a moment. That makes it seem to me that he's looking at the pole when he says that. Even though we can't see the pole ourselves, it makes me feel like there's a pole right there that the characters can see but we can't.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I strongly suspect that there was a pole in the original plans but that somehow got missed out when they were constructing the set.